# printing a tree upside down (with proper indentation and spacing)?

Tags: java, binary-tree

i had a brief look at some questions and answers about normal binary_tree printing .
but i did not find anything about printing them upside down .

the question is :

we have a tree each node is a list of Strings .

```
            A
           / \
          B   C
```

so A is not a character or a single String but a list of Strings.
we want to print each String in a list below the last one .

and we want to print the whole tree like :

```
    B    C
    _______
       A
```

what is the best way to do this .

note: we are not obliged to use standard out put .
maybe using a GUI out put can make things easier .
e.g. text area , text pane or Editor pane etc. (from swing)

two things that i suppose are important are  : "Max depth of each node" AND "Max length of Strings in each String list"

but i think there must be more since using only above attributes for tree below in printing.

```
         A
       /   \ 
      B     C
    /      /  \
   D      E    F
```

gives :

```
   D   E   F
   __________
   B   C   
   ______
   A
```

instead of :

```
  D      E   F
  __     _______
  B        C
  ____________
        A
```

i think we should send a parameter in recursive function for proper spacing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is doing it recursively, i. e. counting the number of children for a given node, than drawing a bar whose length will be proportional to that number, and then call the function inside for all the children nodes.